# What kind of paper did Ghibli use for their storyboards?

Tags: anime-production, hayao-miyazaki, studio-ghibli, the-wind-rises

I googled their *Wind Rises* storyboards and noticed that many of the panels were painted in with watercolor. Does anyone know what kind of paper the studio used, when planning for their films?

I mainly would like to know the fiber/acidity, medium (this one might be redundant though the paper might be multi-media?), dimensions, texture, absorbency. Any approximate answer based on knowledge of common practices in the industry, or specific knowledge of Ghibli's processes (aside from *The Kingdom of Dreams and Madness*, are there other resources to learn more about the production details behind their films?), would be enormously helpful.

And out of curiosity, does anyone know if there are similar kinds of paper, that one could paint over with oil? Or is it just oil painting paper?